# Static string vs non-static string

Tags: c#, string, performance, static

I'm a game programmer, and so I'm always trying to optimize my code. I was playing around with loops lately, and I came across something that confused me a little bit. I created a simple console application and created a non-static class:

```
public class CL
{
    static int X;
    string Z;
    static string sZ;

    public CL(int x, int y, string z)
    {
        X = x + 1;
        Z = z;
        sZ = z;
    }

    public void Update(int i)
    {
        X *= i + 1;
        X = X / 2;
        Z += i.ToString() ;
    }

    public void UpdateStatic(int i)
    {
        X *= i + 1;
        X = X / 2;
        sZ += i.ToString();
    }
}
```

There are two methods that both perform the same operations: they both modify the static integer `X`, and then they add the integer `i` onto the string that is either static (`sZ` in `UpdateStatic`) or not (`Z` in `Update`).

I ran a loop, and here are the results: [image]

As you can see, modifying the static string variable took about 260 times as long as modifying the non-static (which could kill a game's fps). I tried making the integer X both static and not, but there was no performance difference. So my question is: **Why does modifying the static string hurt performance?**, but modifying a static integer not hurt? Here's the rest of the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (Console.ReadLine() != "Q")
        {
            int count = 20000;
            List<CL> l = new List<CL>();
            List<CL> sl = new List<CL>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var cl = new CL(i, i * 2, "");
                l.Add(cl);
                sl.Add(cl);
            }
            Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
            s.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                l[i].Update(i);
            }
            s.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed + " unsorted list modifying non-static variable");
            s.Reset();

            s.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                sl[i].UpdateStatic(i);
            }
            s.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed + " unsorted list modifying static variable");
            s.Reset();
        }

    }
```

I couldn't find anything about why this would happen. Sorry if the answer's obvious. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the non-static version, you are using a different instance of `CL` in every iteration of the loop.  Therefore `Z` never gets very long.

In the static version, `sZ` continues to get longer and longer.

Creating a string and appending has runtime proportional to its length, so the static version takes much longer as a result.

As for the integer, there is no difference in runtime due to the value of an integer.  This is because internally, all integers are the same size in .net.  (4 bytes)